# Get n records group by 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I try all my skills to get result from MySql but its not work for me.

Sample Table:

```
id  period  rid
1   1m      22
2   5m      22
3   1m      33
4   5m      33

5   1m      22
6   5m      22
7   1m      33
8   5m      33

9   1m      22
10  5m      22
```

I want the latest 2 records of each group on 2 columns period,rid

```
OUT PUT
id  period  rid
10  1m      22
9   5m      22
8   1m      33
7   5m      33

6   1m      22
7   5m      22
4   1m      33
3   5m      33
```

There are more periods and Rid, so i need latest 2 records of each group (period,rid)  ORDER BY id DESC

```
SELECT * from docs GROUP BY period,rid ORDER BY id DESC
This query return data of order by ASC
```

MYSQL 5+ so it will work on all servers

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `period` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `rid` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `period`, `rid`) VALUES
  ('1', '1m', '22'),
  ('2', '5m', '22'),
  ('3', '1m', '33'),
  ('4', '5m', '33'),

  ('5', '1m', '22'),
  ('6', '5m', '22'),

  ('7', '1m', '33'),
  ('8', '5m', '33'),
  ('9', '1m', '22'),
  ('10', '5m', '22')
  ;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55ae5/3

Comment: looking at your data, i must confess i really don't think that is possible, as data in a table are by nature **unsorted** what is a group in your case and why you don't have a, column to indicate. as you only 2  rows per some strange grpup why do you not show us how that shoud play out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by period, rid order by id desc) as seqnum
      from docs d
     ) d
where seqnum <= 2
order by id desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91c18f7d05faf7fc9626e5ec2a1fdd04) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that this supports MySQL 8+, which supports window functions.

EDIT:

Assuming that all groups have at least two rows, you can use

```
SELECT d.*
FROM docs d
WHERE d.id >= (SELECT d2.id
               FROM docs d2
               WHERE d2.period = d.period and
                     d2.rid = d.rid
               ORDER BY d2.id DESC
               LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
              );
```

Comment: Is there any solution for MySQL 5+